# bitwise and read a bit

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Unfortunately python can't read a bit from byte.I have the following some bits:

```
var1 = 0b00001111 => 15 in decimal
var2 = 0b 00000010 => 2 in decimal
```

I need to check second bit in var2, or 3th bit in var1.

How to check those?

Comment: What do you mean by "check" and "read a bit from a byte"? If you want to see if the bit is set, why not `(0b10 >> 1) & 1` or `(0b1111 >> 2) & 1`?

Comment: @ggorlen Your comment can be an answer in itself.

Comment: Not necessary because surely this is a duplicate... just hunting for it, and I'm not really sure what OP is asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 0010 and want to check second bit is true or false, You can and with 2:

```
if (0b0010 & 2) == 2 :
    print("two is OK")
if (0b0110 & 4) == 4:
    print("four is ok")
```

Answer (score -3):

You can run something like `bin(var2)[::-1][1]` to get the second least significant bit.

Comment: What's the point of converting a binary number to a string just to test whether a bit is set? Doesn't this pretty much defeat the purpose of using binary?

Comment: True that, how about bitwise AND-ing then?